# Would Aspect of the Beast (Night Senses) grant Darkvision to a Druid Wild-Shaped into a form with Low Light Vision?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, wild-shape

Aspect of the Beast: "Benefit: Your bestial nature manifests itself in one of the following ways. You choose the manifestation when you choose the feat, and then you cannot change it.

Night Senses (Ex): If your base race has normal vision, you gain low-light vision. If your base race has low-light vision, you gain darkvision out to a range of 30 feet. If your base race has darkvision, the range of your darkvision increases by 30 feet."

If a Human Druid took the Aspect of the Beast feat for the Night Senses, he or she would of course gain Low Light Vision. But what if they then Wild Shaped into a form that already had Low Light Vision (such as most animals)--would that form then qualify as the "base race" and thus grant the animal form Darkvision?

Answer (score 4):

A [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) effect (like the [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid)'s supernatural ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-)) causes the affected creature to lose extraordinary and supernatural abilities dependent upon on his original form, including keen senses, scent, darkvision, natural attacks, and movement modes. This should include any enhancements due to having taken the feat [Aspect of the Beast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/aspect-of-the-beast) (night senses), as the senses granted by the feat are explicitly extraordinary abilities *and* the feat's effects appear tied to his original form.

However, there's room for a generous GM to rule otherwise: The [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) rules also say that while changes to a character's abilities "should be obvious, the GM is the final arbiter of what abilities depend on form and are lost when a new form is assumed." So you could pay for pizza then ask the GM.

Nonetheless, a druid's base race is always the druid's original race. Changing race *temporarily* doesn't alter the druid's *base* race. Being brought back from the dead by the spell [*reincarnate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate), for example, changes a creature's base race.